# Erro fetch_assoc() on boolean

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou com esse erro na minha aplicação:

> Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean

Executo a mesma aplicação no servidor local e nao retorna erro, no servidor de dist, retorna o erro acima.

O erro é gerado nessa linha:

```
<?php
$photos = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE galeria_id = {$album_id}");
while($photo_data = $photos->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     <div class="thumbnail">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="admin/webroot/img/galerias/<?php echo $album_id; ?>/<?php echo $photo_data['image'] ?>" />
                        </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: O ponto que deve ter gerado esse erro é `{$album_id}` ser nulo/vazio

Comment: o `$conexão->query(...)` retorna `false` se a query falhar. Provavelmente seu album_id é null, vazio ou uma string, e por isso o erro ocorre.

Comment: Estava dando erro por não estar recebendo o atributo get que vinha de outra pagina.